# RSS app for iPad, that support https? (ssl-over-http)

Tags: rss, ipad

I'm trying to find an RSS-app for iPad, that supports https-protocol.

Tried **The Feed** and **News Reader for iPad**, but they don't want to accept links with https proto-supplied(rss generated from Pivotal Tracker, and includes latest tasks for project).

Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Reeder](http://reederapp.com/ipad/)? I don't know for sure that it supports this, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: Reeder syncs with Google Reader, so the requirement for HTTPS would therefore lie with Google Reader.